# How to access model function in view or blade file

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent, model

I want to get interest amount which is multiple of amount and interest rate in a table "loan". I want to call the value from a table and used for display loan information.

I have tried using mutators in which case gives same error as mentioned below

**Loan.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['amount', 'interest', 'status', 'member_id', 'loan_type_id', 'interest_type_id', 'loan_payment_type_id'];

    public function getInterestAmountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->amount * $this->interest;
    }

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**loan.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Loan Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Interest</th>
        <th>Interest Amount</th>
        <th>Interest Type</th>
        <th>Loan Type</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Payment Type</th>
        <th>Member</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach($loanData as $key=>$loan)
        <tr>
            <td>{{++$key}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan->amount}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan->interest}}</td>
            <td>{{ $loan->interest_amount}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan->interesttype->interest_type}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan->loantype->loan_type}}</td>
            <td align="center">

                <span class="bg bg-primary" style="border-radius: 10px;padding:2px 5px">{{$loan->status}}</span>

                <form action="{{route('update-loan-status')}}" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="{{$loan->id}}"/>
                    @if($loan->status== 1)
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" name="paid"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                    @endif
                    @if($loan->status== 0)
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="unpaid"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                    @endif
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>{{$loan->paymentmethod->method}}</td>
            <td>{{$loan->member->name}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="">Delete</a>
                <a href="">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </thead>
</table>
{{$loanData->links()}}
```

This gives the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

when I remove brackets

```
 <td>{{$loan->getInterest}}</td>
```

the error is

> App\Loan::getInterest must return a relationship instance.

**LoanController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Loan;
use App\Interest;
use App\LoanPaymentMethod;
use App\Member;
use App\Loantype;
use DB;

class LoanController extends Controller
{
    protected $_backendPath = 'backend.';
    protected $_pagePath = 'backend.pages.';
    protected $_data = [];

    public function index()
    {
        $loanData = Loan::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        $loanData = Loan::paginate(10);
        $loanData = Loan::all();
        $memberData = Member::all();
        $loantypeData = Loantype::all();
        $paymentmethodData = LoanPaymentMethod::all();
        $interestData = Interest::all();
        $this->_data['loanData'] = $loanData;

        //$results = Loan::with('member')->get();
        //$dat->loan = Loan::with('member')->get();
        //$loan = Member::find($memberData)->loan;

        return view($this->_pagePath . 'loan.loan', $this->_data);

        //$userData = DB::table('members')->get();
        //return view('home',compact('userData'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist."? Because you would have to call getInterest with the `()` afterwards.

Comment: it gives a error you mentioned when i use brackets after function name.

Comment: Prithvi Tuladhar , i provide a solution for this , please update if you have any issue in my solution

Comment: i have tried it and the error is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append that variable in model data Like

```
class Loan extends Model
{
     protected $appends = ['interest'];
}
```

Your accessor should like

```
public function getInterest()
{
  return $this->amount * $this->interest;
}
```

Access in blade file as you use above

```
<td>{{$loan->interest}}</td>
```

Comment: @PrithviTuladhar please use directly {{ $loan->interest }} in blade

Comment: it cannot be called as {{ $loan -> interest}}. {{ $loan -> interest }} has  been used here to fetch interest rate. i need interest amount to be computed.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function as accessor in your Loan.php :

```
public function getGetInterestAttribute()
{
   return $this->amount * $this->interest;
}
```

Now you can access it , like this :

```
<td>{{ $loan->get_interest }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to call an Accessor,

```
public function getModifiedInterestAttribute()    // first get then ModifiedInterest then Attribute
{
  return $this->amount * $this->interest;
}
```

Then you can call the Accessor like below,

```
<td>{{$loan->modified_interest }}</td>
```

You can see this for more details : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: do it need to use    " protected $appends = ['interest']; " as suggested above?? the error is same

Comment: If you would like computed values to be added to the array / JSON representations of your model, you will need to append them.

Comment: i may not need it to be stored but i am still getting error with or without using append. do i have to mention anything in the code such as use Illuminate.........

Comment: If you do as i suggested it should work. You can see the official documentation also if you don't understand.

Comment: i used accessor as you suggested and all, it gives "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist."? error. can you tell me why i am getting this error as i have not  used "Collection" whatsoever.

Comment: did you use pagination in your view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191886/discussion-between-md-sukel-ali-and-prithvi-tuladhar).